# non-asci characters ending up in database

Tags: drupal, mysql

Today we spent about 2 hours bashing our heads trying to get a string compare to work so we could run a query against contact sub type while setting up a new participant public listing.

We started realizing what was going on when the string length getting returned was 7. When it should have been 5, for Child. Took a look at it in the command line and saw this:

[image: Extra characters]

Anyone know why they might have ended up in the database? And how to avoid them showing up again?

Thanks!

I think this was also the problem behind [another question I asked here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9009/how-can-i-make-a-filter-to-exclude-someone-who-has-a-certain-tag-assigned-to-the) previously.

drupal 7
civicrm 4.6.11

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CiviCRM historically uses the CRM_Core_DAO::VALUE_SEPARATOR character as a serialization technique for storing multiple values in a field. Best practice is use the API for accessing values, or if you really want to do direct database access then you need to treat that value as a multiple value separator.

Comment: Oops. That makes sense. So would Drupal Views do this correctly then and use the API? Because the behavior I was seeing there, unable to query custom data field values unless I set to the fields to a text field and then searched for NULL fields in order to exclude records in the results strikes me as very similar to what we were seeing with this.

Comment: I'm not sure about views. Just browsing the code I would assume it's in the render() function here and it seems to handle it appropriately, but I can't confirm just by looking this is actually where it happens. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/civicrm/civicrm-drupal/7.x-4.6/modules/views/civicrm/civicrm_handler_field_custom.inc

Answer (score 1):

To enhance a little on Demerit's correct answer, this is what I do in PHP when I need to separate contact_sub_types or case_types (which have the same setup in the database):

```
$typeIds = explode(CRM_Core_DAO::VALUE_SEPARATOR, $value);
$value   = array();
foreach ($typeIds as $typeId) {
  $value[$typeId] = $this->_caseTypes[$typeId];
}
$rows[$rowNum]['case_type'] = implode(', ', $value);
```

Or if you need to create a query and use the VALUE_SEPARATOR in a clause do something like this:

```
 $where .= " ( " . $field . " LIKE CONCAT ('%" . CRM_Core_DAO::VALUE_SEPARATOR . "'," . $filter['value'] . ",'" . CRM_Core_DAO::VALUE_SEPARATOR . "%') ) AND ";
```